# permutation of pairs in GA

Tags: matlab

I want to do a change in GA, this is my code:

```
nvar=16;
options=gaoptimset('PlotFcns'{@gaplotbestf},'PopulationType','custom',
'TolFun',1e4,'CreationFcn',@mycreate,'CrossoverFcn',@mycross,
'MutationFcn',@mymutate,'PopulationSize',10*nvar);
p=[ 1 3.2 5 2  3 2.7 1.5 2  3 2 6 3.3  1.5 2.3 4 2.5 2 3 3.2 1.2 3 5 6.5 4 9 8 2.1 3 5 7.6 4 3 ];
a=AB;
b=B;
FitnessFCN=@(x) myfitness(x,p,a,b);
[x,fval,reason,output]=ga(FitnessFCN,nvar,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],options);
```

The vector with 32 elemnts is a actually a vector with 16 pairs, I mean:

```
p=[ (1 3.2) (5 2)  (3 2.7) (1.5 2)  (3 2) (6 3.3)  (1.5 2.3) (4 2.5) (2 3) (3.2 1.2) (3 5) (6.5 4) (9 8) (2.1 3) (5 7.6) (4 3) ];
```

I want GA do the permutation of pairs not all the elemnts, I mean the second vector not the first vector, but the GA do the GA on 32 elements.I mean the x that GA returns me must be a vector with 16 pairs. Thanks.

Comment: you have to post the function myfitness for other people to understand what is happening in your code. but if the question can be answered by how to make 16 pairs instead of 32 values try: p=p=[ 1 3.2; 5 2;  3 2.7; 1.5 2] to create a 16x2 matrix and then adress each row of the matrix

Comment: @Finn: Thanks you.